# microk8s Connection to port 16443 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'm getting following error message:

```
root@master-1:~# microk8s.kubectl get no
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:16443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Even `microk8s.kubectl cluster-info dump` fails with message above. When I run `microk8s start` it still the same.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is swap turned off? 2. Have you checked if the kubeconfig file is present? (`$HOME/.kube/config`)

Comment: to be able to help you first provide accurate information how you spinned up/configured cluster. Not enough info to help at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables were provisioned by ansible which were messing with microk8s iptables configuration

Comment: Hi @hejkerooo what did you do with the iptables configuration from ansible? how did you disable it?

Comment: I've removed iptables provisioning from ansible, that's it

Comment: Is there maybe a guide on how to go about doing this? thank you!

Comment: What exactly did you do, can you explain?

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to tell exactly what might went wrong here but there are few things that you could do in order to fix your issue:

- `.kube/config` is missing or not configured correctly. Create or copy a valid [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#:%7E:text=The%20kubectl%20command%2Dline%20tool,of%20referring%20to%20configuration%20files.) file to solve this.
- You have `swap` not turned off. With `swap` enabled, kubelet service will not start. Execute: `sudo swapoff -a` in order to make sure it is disabled.
- `kubelet` might be down. Check `kubelet` logs and make sure that `kube-apiserver` is up and running.
- Check which ports are appropriate to use with the `telnet` command.

Comment: that answer helped?

Comment: turning swap off after a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 lts in VirtualBox was the key for me. thx

Answer (score 1):

For me **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)**, this two commands save my day:

```
sudo microk8s.refresh-certs --cert ca.crt
```

and

```
sudo microk8s.refresh-certs --cert server.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

check your /etc/ hosts file
there should be these lines

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 name you servers

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is already an ip address, it's not related to hosts file

Comment: @Pezhvak 127.0.0.1 is a special, reserved IP address.  It is called the loopback address. The hostname localhost  is used for 127.0.0.1 and it's normal to see a couple of lines relating 127.0.0.1 to localhost and to the host name.